# iOS - Nested ScrollViews and passing gestures to sibling subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiscrollview

I have the following view structure:

ScrollView A (horizontal)

- ScrollView B (horizontal)
- ViewC (collection view)

ScrollView A takes up the full screen and pages between weeks, ScrollView B is a subview of A, and also takes up the full screen and pages between days. 
The idea is that ScrollView B completely overlays A, and handles all paging until the start or end of the week is reached. At that point the B cannot scroll and further and all paging then automatically gets caught by A which then pages by week.
This all works fine "out of the box", however I have a ViewC that is also a subview of A (and as such also gets paged by it) which "floats" over scrollviewB and as such does not scroll with it.

My issue: ViewC is a sibling of ScrollViewB, not a child, and as such (even though with respect to z-index ScrollViewB sits underneath it) swipes gestures done on it are passed to ScrollView A... whereas I would like them to be passed on to ScrollView B.

How can I achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: too many scrollviews imho. u should rethink about this design.

Comment: Add a swipeGesture on *viewC* and in its selector just use the scroll to the calculated offset of *scrollViewB*. **Or** you could check in `scrollViewDidScroll` if your `UIScrollView` is *ScrollView A* and then scroll to a contentOffSet of *ScrollView B* (Assuming scrolling on *scrollView A* cannot be done by the user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but if ViewC is a static information view, does it really need to be a subview of ScrollViewA?

Assuming your implementation works without ViewC (it sounds like it should), and that ViewC doesn't require any interaction itself, you should simply be able to make ViewC a sibling of ScrollViewA, and pass all touches through it to whichever scrollview is currently active based on your logic. You can do this by subclassing UIView and overwriting `-(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` to return NO.

**Edit:**

Given that the static view does have its own interactions, it sounds like you'll be best off replacing ScrollViewB and ViewC with a subclassed UICollectionView. You can add the static overlay view as a subview, and position it in `layoutSubviews`.

The other advantage of a UICollectionView is that you can scroll to a specific item using `scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`. Depending on your implementation of ViewC, and how it passes on which day has been tapped, it should be pretty easy to scroll to the respective day.

That said, it sounds like you've already got it all working (except for the overlay), including scrolling to specific items, so you may be better off just subclassing UISCrollView and adding the overlay as a subview. That way you can reuse all of your existing logic such as scrolling to a specific day, and it should fix your scrolling issue.

Comment: Ok, I should of elaborated. So ViewC is a summary of the week and does get "paged' with ScrollView A. Likewise it does have its own interactions in terms of selecting days (which would programmatically scroll ScrollView B to the picked day).

Comment: OK. Have you considered using a UICollectionView instead? It sounds like you can replace both ScrollViewB and ViewC with a subclassed UICollectionView. You can add the static information view and position it in `layoutSubviews`, and you can also handle scrolling to specific days.

Comment: Actually, I'm still making assumptions. Is ViewC a custom view? How do the interactions work? i.e. does a user tap a UIButton to scroll to a day?

Comment: Hmm UICollectionView is worth a consideration, may tinker around with that. With regards to your other question: yes it is a subclassed collection view and tapping a cell scrolls to a day.

Comment: If you already have everything working (except for the overlay view), a UICollectionView sounds like it may be a little overkill, since it will require additional setup of the data source and delegate methods such as `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, and by the sounds of it would likely end up just being a slightly nicer implementation of what you've already done. It may be sufficient to just subclass UIScrollView and add the overlay view as a subview. Hard to say without knowing exactly how things have been implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, as I said i'll tinker around with your suggestions and if it works out ill mark as answer :)